# Encrypt web.config without command line tool

Tags: asp.net, .net, encryption, web-config, asp.net-4.0

I want to encrypt my `appSettings` and `ConnectionStrings` that located on my `web.config` file.

But since I'm using a shared hosting, I can't use `aspnet_regiis.exe` method.

Is there any other way to encrypt `web.config` file? (an online tool, a remote tool, a programming way, or...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested by me, from CodeProject, hope that it will work
**Aspx Code:**

```
 <asp:Button id="btnEncrypt" runat="server" Text="Encrypt" onclick="btnEncrypt_Click" />
 <asp:Button ID="btnDecrypt" runat="server" Text="Decrypt" onclick="btnDecrypt_Click" />

 Code Behind:

    string provider = "RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider";
    string section = "connectionStrings";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Configuration confg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
       ConfigurationSection configSect = confg.GetSection(section);
       if (configSect != null)
       {
          configSect.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
          confg.Save();
       }
    }

    protected void btnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
       ConfigurationSection configSect = config.GetSection(section);
       if (configSect.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
       {
          configSect.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
          config.Save();
       }
    }
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/304638/Encrypt-or-Decrypt-Connection-Strings-in-web-confi

Comment: What is other possible values for `section` variable? (for application settings, etc.)

Comment: for application setting : appSettings.